# Can わざわざ or わざと be used for oneself?

Tags: words

I want to say "Even though I didn't have time, I went out of my way to..." (not a dialogue, just an essay reflecting on my stupidity).

> 時間がなかったのに、わざと...

(In case this is a silly question: I just watched a video explaining the difference between わざわざ and わざと, but all of the examples used described the actions of other people (namely 'you'--"Thanks for coming while you're busy", "You punched me on purpose didn't you", etc.). After reading that くせに can't be used for oneself, I began to wonder if it was true for the mentioned expressions too. Is there a list somewhere that lists all of the 'can't use for yourself' words?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. わざわざ and わざと can be used for yourself.

> 母「またこぼすとわかっているのに**わざわざ**拭いて{ふいて}あげた」
>   *Mother: I took the trouble to clean it up for you, even though I know you'll spill it again.*
>   子「拭いて{ふいて}もらえるとわかっていたから**わざと**こぼした」
>   *Child: I spilled it on purpose, knowing that you'll clean it up.*

---

It's true that くせに is mostly used for other people, but not always. For example, 何も知らないくせに! as an insult is used toward others, but you can also use it for yourself in a humbling way:

> 何も知らないくせに口を挟んで{はさんで}しまった
>   *I interjected despite not knowing anything*

A similar thing can be said for おかげで. While mostly used for other people, it can also be used for yourself or your own actions:

> - あんなに練習{れんしゅう}したおかげで成功{せいこう}した
>     *I succeeded, thanks to all that practicing.*
> - 私のおかげでプロジェクトが成功したんだから感謝{かんしゃ}しなさい
>     *The project succeed thanks to me, so be grateful.* (self-aggrandizing)
> - 私が失敗{しっぱい}したおかげでチームが負けて{まけて}しまった
>     *The team lost, thanks to my mistake.* (sarcastic/self-deprecating)

So, even if there were such a list of “can't use for yourself” words, it would probably need a lot of clarification…